# Spring Security login won't work when dealing with 2 tomcat and nginx

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nginx, spring-security

I have two same webapps deployed on tomcat at 127.0.0.1:8090 and 127.0.0.1:8091. I want to distribute requests between these two apps, so I config the nginx like this:

```
upstream my_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:8090;
    server 127.0.0.1:8091 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.testabcd.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location /myapp {
        proxy_pass http://my_servers;
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine then. So I moved forward, removed the "backup", the config now looks like this:

```
upstream my_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:8090;
    server 127.0.0.1:8091;
}

server {
    ...
}
```

However, my app's login just wouldn't take any effect! I visit http://testabcd.com/my_servers/hello/ and it keep returning the login page!

Below is some details of my app:

My webapp is working with Spring Security 3.1.4, and the login configuration part in the applicationContext.xml is like this:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/access_denied" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/access_denied"/>
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/hello/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
</sec:http>
```

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The login.jsp：

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<form id="form2" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method="post">
        <label>email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" value="${sessionScope['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']}"/><br/>  
        <label>password:</label>  
        <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password"/><br/>
        <label>rememberme:</label>  
        <input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" />  
        <br/>  
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />  
</form>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to debug which backend servers the requests are actually being routed to? The [nginx upstream module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule) apparently uses round-robin load balancing, so what you're observing seems normal. You login and start a session on one backend server, and subsequently arrive at a different one which has no knowledge of the session (unless you are clustering sessions between them which I'd guess not).

Ideally you'll need to use a sticky-session load-balancer, based on the JSESSIONID cookie. I don't think nginx supports this out of the box, but you can set the [`ip_hash`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule#ip_hash) directive so that individual IP addresses always use the same backend server.

Comment: I also tackled the same problem but resolved it using hazelcast (in memory data grid) and a custom implementation of the spring security context repository (SecurityContextRepository).